# Get rid of the ugly notification osd in lubuntu 14.10

Tags: lubuntu, notification, notify-osd

I installed lubuntu 14.10 recently. I love it so far. It's very fast and all. The only absolute one thing that really annoys me is the "out-of-shape" osd which is used for notifications. I haven't seen anything as ugly as this. I wouldn't mind if it takes to removing it, but I definately don't want it there. Any work-around? Here is an [Image.](http://i60.tinypic.com/2ytwtav.jpg)

Comment: modify the lubuntu panel and remove the notification area or disable lxpanet altogether (and use just openbox without a panel, or use tint2 as an alternate). You have several options here. http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201010/page07.html

Comment: how do I remove just the notification area? I like the panel though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how the panel is intended to look - this is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-artwork/+bug/1362555 (If you know how to use launchpad, please feel free to report that this bug also affects you.)

This file: `/usr/share/themes/Lubuntu-default/gtk-2.0/images/panel-bg.png` is the background of that notification and is tiled.

You could try removing that file or replacing that file with an image of your choice. Replacing it with a nice solid color or gradient would be a good option.

Or, here is an alternative workaround: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-artwork/+bug/1362555/comments/14

Comment: I have reported the bug. Thank you. Glad to know there is a workaround. I don't know how such silly mistakes creep in.

Comment: Fixed. Opened the image in `mtpaint` and filled it with grey. Will experiment with more in future. http://i62.tinypic.com/2ag2329.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a workaround described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-artwork/+bug/1362555/comments/6):

> Looks like broken theming. You can easily check by installing the package shimmer-themes and setting the notification theme (in xfce4-notifyd-config) to "Greybird". That should fix it.

`shimmer-themes` is available via the Lubuntu Software Center or you can just run `sudo apt-get install shimmer-themes`.

Then click on `Notifications` under `Preferences` to change to the Greybird theme for notifications. Doing so will only affect your onscreen notifications and nothing else. Of course, you can just use Greybird for everything if you wish.